How to delete a stubborn critical error notification in FreePBX?
We have this critical error message on our dashboard of FreePBX:

We appear to have fixed the underlying cause of the notification, but when we click the (-) button to Ignore it, it comes back again after refreshing. There is no (x) Delete button for this notification.
How can we permenantly delete this stubborn notification?


Login to SSH and run:
mysql -uroot


Execute:
use asterisk;
select * from notifications;



Replace the timestamp below with the one from the notification in question
update notifications set candelete=1 where timestamp=1705643520;


Refresh the homepage

A (x) Delete button will now be showing

Click it to delete the notification


